# How to view pdf file with chrome on android

Tags: pdf

I downloaded a pdf file on Windows and transferred it to my android phone. I want to know if there is any way to view the file using chrome browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't. Chrome on Desktop/Linux uses Chrome PDF Viewer, a plug-in. Plug-ins are not supported by Chrome on Android.

Source: [Quora](https://www.quora.com/Why-does-Chrome-on-Android-not-open-PDF-files-like-Chrome-on-Windows-Linux-can)